# Qt creator: unable to run application on Windows Mobile 10

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtquick2, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to run my QtQuick project on Windows Mobile (nokia lumia 735). I have managed to build the project and launch on the device, the problem is that it always show a blank screen. The console log says the following:

```
qt.winrtrunner: Using the AppxPhone profile.
qt.winrtrunner: No mapping file exists. Only recognized files will be packaged.
qt.winrtrunner: App started with process ID 1768
```

I am using Qt Creator.